# Upload to Firebase storage tasks about 30 minutes

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

The following code tasks very long to complete.  Any ideas?

```
Future<String> uploadFile({required File file}) async {
    //String downloadURL = "";

    final fileName = file.uri.pathSegments.last;
    final uuid = Uuid();
    final filePath = "videos/${uuid.v4()}_$fileName";
    debugPrint(filePath);
    final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath);
    final uploadTask = storage.putFile(file);

    final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
    final downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return downloadURL;
}
```

Comment: I think the file size matters,  what is the file size in your case?

Comment: The video is only 3 seconds long.  So, I wouldn't imagine it is that large.  I would need to try and find its exact size

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things that can cause a slow upload:

1. large file size (big difference)
2. slow network connection (big difference)
3. distance to firebase project location (minimal difference)

I don't see anything wrong in your code. I would recommend to check the file size and the network speed. Even 3 sec video with hogh resolution can get quite big. Always try to reduce the size of file you upload. Even images.